# UIScrollview shifting contents up after scrolling down and pushing new viewcontroler

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have trouble figuring out this issue on my uiscrollview. The contents inside my uiscrollview  move up after clicking a button to push a new view controller onto the screen, and then going back to the original view controller. Notice how the the top of the scrollview changes.

[image]    [image]

Here is the code for the scrollView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(923, 934)];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
}
```

Comment: Write this in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];

Comment: When I do this, the uiscrollview goes to the top, but everything is still shifted up (the top portion on the content is still out of the view).

Comment: just noticed how this would seem confusing to others, so I added new pictures of the shift

Comment: Just to confirm: iOS 6? If you log the table view's `contentInset` and `contentOffset` within `viewDidAppear:` then does that provide any clues? The scrollbar appears to confirm that nothing odd is happening to the view's frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0)];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because of the way that the autoLayout is done when creating views. For some reason when you first add a view to the screen (the scrollview), the view's coordinates don't include under the navigationbar, but after another view is added, they do. One way that I get around this is by creating a blank view and adding it as a subview before adding the scrollView.

Such as:

```
UIView *vi = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, -10, 1, 1)]
[vi setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:vi];
//Then add scrollView
```

This just creates an offscreen 1x1 clear view and adds it to the main view which makes the main view properly locate itself before adding the scrollView.

You also might want to change the y coordinate of your scrollView, as doing this with your current code will make it always behave as in the second case.

I usually do:

```
frame.y+=self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20;
```

which adds the navigation bar height and the status bar height (20).

Comment: When I do  scroll.frame.origin.y +=self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20; it gives me an error of "Expression is not assignable"

Comment: You dont neccessarily do that, but when you do create the scrollView, add that number to whatever the y would have been.

Comment: But doesn't that shift the whole thing down 20 when it loads? I only have this shifting problem after I scroll down and then push a new view controller. Initially, the scrollview always loads fine, but only after scrolling down, pushing views, and then going back does the whole thing shift

Comment: That's why you add the blank view first. It makes it act more similarly to when you go back from another view.

Comment: Doing that doesnt seem to fix the issue

Comment: I do 
    
    UIView *vi = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 500)];
    [vi setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:vi];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

Comment: You might be experiencing a different problem then. A few weeks ago, the same thing was happening to me and adding a dummy view then moving everything's coordinates downscreen fixed it.

Comment: hmm I am even making the dummy view and scroll view correctly in the code?

Comment: try putting them in viewDidLoad instead of viewDidAppear.

Comment: no that still doesnt seem to work. This shift only happens if you scroll all the way down in the scrollview and then push a new view controller if this helps with anything.

Comment: I was tearing my hair out about this. This completely fixed it. This has got to be a major bug. It makes no sense that adding a view would change the next view added.

Comment: Also fixed in storyboard by adding an empty view behind the scroll view. Insane.

Answer (score 1):

At first I used your answer) But after some time I found the solution how to fix this problem without scrolling each time content to the top. Hope it will work for you)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22699785/246598